# Python - Summing elements on list of lists based on first element of inner lists

Tags: python

I have a list

```
[[0.5, 2], [0.5, 5], [2, 3], [2, 6], [2, 0.6], [7, 1]]
```

I require the output from summing the second element in each sublist for a unique first element. In this case it is:

```
[[0.5, 7], [2, 9.6], [7, 1]]
```

Where `[0.5, 7]` is summing the second element of `[0.5, 2]` and `[0.5, 5]`.

What would be the most efficient way to do this for say lists of length 1,000.

Comment: Can you use pandas or numpy?  A groupby is the way to go here, its essentially what your asking.  Writing you're own groupby function, if you've never done it before, is a huge pain.

Comment: Is your input list sorted by the first element?

Comment: lists of length 1000 is tiny. pandas/numpy groupy would be quite overkill for that.

Comment: @jpp Not sorted but I want to retain the same order in the output.

Comment: @AndrewK, Then I suggest `collections.defaultdict`, O(*n*) complexity and avoids Pandas / NumPy overhead for the small arrays you are working with.

Comment: @JamieMarshall I can use but trying to keep it simple. I haven't used groupby but I will look into it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accumulate with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(int)
>>> L = [[0.5, 2], [0.5, 5], [2, 3], [2, 6], [2, 0.6], [7, 1]]
>>> for k, v in L:
...     data[k] += v
...     
>>> [[k,v] for (k,v) in data.items()]
[[0.5, 7], [2, 9.6], [7, 1]]
```

Note that the value for 2 was automatically "promoted" to a float by addition, even though this is a defaultdict of int.  This is to match the desired output posted in the question, but I think you should consider to use homogeneous output types rather than a mix of int and float.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use defaultdict though. How would I get this to a list with the same order as the original?

Comment: `list(data.items())` should do it on Python 3.6+.

Comment: My input values will all be float. Will this always retain my original ordering of the list?

Comment: To retain original ordering pre-py3.6, use OrderedDict with setdefault.

Comment: How would I get the output to `[[0.5, 7], [2, 9.6], [7, 1]]` instead of `[(0.5, 7), (2, 9.6), (7, 1)]`?

Comment: @AndrewK  `l = [list(tup) for tup in data.items()]`

Comment: Do you have any good reason to care if the elements are lists and not tuples..?

Comment: @wim Mutability?

Comment: Not really but I am new to python and I thought lists perform functions like append and delete faster.

Comment: @wim can I rely on the defaultdict to retain the same order as the original list? For example if original is `[[2, 3], [0.5, 2], [0.5, 5], [2, 6], [2, 0.6], [7, 1]]` I need to be sure the output is `[[2, 9.6], [0.5, 7], [7, 1]]`

Comment: @AndrewK  It's reliable on CPython 3.6+ or Python  3.7+.  What version of Python do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas, you can retain the original 'order' of the data:

```
pairs = [[0.5, 2], [0.5, 5], [2, 3], [2, 6], [2, 0.6], [7, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(pairs)
>>> [tup[0] for tup in zip(df.groupby(0, sort=False, as_index=False).sum().values.tolist())]
[[0.5, 7.0], [2.0, 9.6], [7.0, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with sorting and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

data = [[0.5, 2], [0.5, 5], [2, 3], [2, 6], [2, 0.6], [7, 1]]

key = itemgetter(0)
data.sort(key=key)  # Use data = sorted(data, key=key) to avoid clobbering
result = [[k, sum(group)] for k, group in groupby(data, key)]
```

This will not preserve the original order of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
L = [[0.5, 2], [0.5, 5], [2, 3], [2, 6], [2, 0.6], [7, 1]]
nums = []
d = {}
for lst in L:
    if lst[0] not in d:
        d[lst[0]] = []
        nums.append(lst[0])
    d[lst[0]].append(lst[1])

for key in nums:
    print [key, sum(d[key])]
```

Output:

```
[0.5, 7]
[2, 9.6]
[7, 1]
```